# Athens open on Sunday?

Tags: greece, athens, opening-hours

I'm going to have a free day in Athens between two trips -- I should arrive there some time Saturday, and then leave on Sunday afternoon.

However, I've been warned that many tourist attractions such as the Acropolis might be closed on Sunday -- is it true? I can't easily find an official source online, and I am afraid that the opening times might have changed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Official hours are available from the [Ministry of Culture](http://odysseus.culture.gr/index_en.html) website, and all the locations I checked meshed with hours posted on independent websites.

The major monuments, museums, and archeological sites in Athens are open on Sundays, even in winter, for example

- [Acropolis](http://odysseus.culture.gr/h/3/eh355.jsp?obj_id=2384) and [Acropolis Museum](http://www.theacropolismuseum.gr/en/content/hours-ticketing)
- [Ancient Agora](http://odysseus.culture.gr/h/3/eh355.jsp?obj_id=2485) and [Ancient Agora Museum](http://odysseus.culture.gr/h/1/eh155.jsp?obj_id=3290)
- [Kerameikos](http://odysseus.culture.gr/h/3/eh355.jsp?obj_id=2392)
- [National Archeological Museum](http://odysseus.culture.gr/h/1/eh155.jsp?obj_id=3249)
- [Olympeion](http://odysseus.culture.gr/h/3/eh355.jsp?obj_id=2488) (Temple of the Olympic Zeus)
- [Roman Agora](http://odysseus.culture.gr/h/3/eh355.jsp?obj_id=2402)

Smaller museums close on Mondays, especially in the off-season, as is common in Western countries. They will also close on more public holidays.

The ministry website is incomplete; for example, it lists no hours for the Theatre of Dionysus Eluthereos or for the Temple of Hephaestus. You will need to rely on other sources, as with monasteries and other private attractions which set their own hours for when visitors are permitted.

Comment: Are restaurant really closed on Sundays? That is surprising to me...

Comment: @Bernhard Places that cater to workers are more likely to be closed than places that cater to tourists, of course.

Comment: Many tavernas will be open on Sunday, but you are right shopping is limited on a Sunday.

Comment: Restaurants/tavernas are definetely NOT closed on Sundays. Shops are indeed closed.